# SqlMembershipProvider question

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, asp.net-2.0, sqlmembershipprovider

When you create the Register Control for the SqlMembersipProvider nothing happens if they register and the username or email is in use. Is there a tutorial or override function that fixes this in asp.net 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to register an event handler for the `LoginError` event.

See this article for lots of details: https://web.archive.org/web/20210513220018/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx

Comment: There is no answer on that site regarding my question

Comment: It's not a loginError aswell it's a registration issue Im talking about like a username that's already in use or an email address

Answer (score 1):

You most certainly should see a red error message indicating that the operation failed and why.

If you do not see this then there is something hinky with the way you have built your create-user page.

Try simply dragging a CreateUserWizard onto a new WebForm and try what you describe.

---

And nick is correct in saying that you really should acknowledge the time and effort people take to help you with your problems by taking  *2 seconds* and clicking upvote and/or accept.

That is the way that stackoverflow works and if you don't get with the program you are going to be ignored.