# ASP.NET Classes Question

Tags: c#, asp.net

Could someone tell me the difference between

```
static public
public static
```

and

```
private int _myin = 0
public int MyInt
{
    get{ return _myInt; }
    private set {_myInt = value; }
}
```

the private set part is what I want to know

Comment: Why is this question specific to ASP.NET? I would think this is just a general question against C#.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first 2 are no different, you can order the modifiers however you like, though this is more common:

```
public static
```

The second, it means that the property can only be *set* within the class, but can get gotten publicly, by anyone with a reference.

E.g. this only works inside the class:

```
MyInt = 123;
```

But this works anywhere:

```
int Temp = MyClass.MyInt;
```

And as another example, this would fail:

```
var mc = new MyClass();
mc.MyInt = 123; //this won't compile, it's not a public setter
```

Comment: are you able to anwser my SqlMembership Question aswell.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313771/sqlmembershipprovider-question

Comment: @littleMan - I'm afraid that's not my area of expertise, however I will retag the question so it shows up on the radar of those with that expertise :)

Comment: So you can only set its value inside the class

Comment: @littleMan - That's correct, it's acts just like a `private int MyInt` when it comes to *setting* it.